# Pierce decomposition of a (not necessarily commutative) ring and the cartesian product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

Let $R$ be a (not necessarily) commutative ring and $e \in R$ some idempotent. Then the [Pierce decomposition](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Peirce_decomposition) writes
$$ 
R=eRe \oplus (1-e)Re \oplus eR(1-e) \oplus (1-e)R(1-e).
$$
I tried to construct such an isomorphism, specifically consider the cartesian product $eRe \times eR(1-e) \times (1-e)Re \times (1-e)R(1-e)$, and the mapping
$$
 \varphi(r) = (ere, re - ere, er - ere, r - er - (re - ere)).
$$
Then this is bijective. And also it is an isomorphism of $(R, +)$
and the additive group we get by componentwise addition on this cartesian product.

But the only case that multiplication makes any sense is when $e$ is central, i.e. commutes with all elements, otherwise I am not even able to define multiplication componentwise in the above case. But the Pierce decomposition, for example also [here](http://www.tricki.org/article/Decompose_your_ring_using_idempotents) and in the above link, does not require the idempotents to be central. So I am unable how this decomposition should work out, and I am surprised by the above inconsistencies? So could anyone explain them?

Also for the preservation of the additive structure, and surjectivity and injectivity of $\varphi$ nowhere is it needed that we have $e^2 = e$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I am not even able to define multiplication componentwise".  Even if $e$ is not central, $eRe$ and all the other components are closed under multiplication as subsets of $R$, so you can use that to define multiplication componentwise.  Of course, the problem remains that $\varphi$ may not preserve multiplication.

Comment: @EricWofsey Okay, yes surely the sets $eRe$ etc are subrings. So is there a way to give an isomorphism, i.e. are they isomorphic then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Peirce decomposition is only additive, not multiplicative.  That is, $R$ is only isomorphic to $eRe \oplus (1-e)Re \oplus eR(1-e) \oplus (1-e)R(1-e)$ as an additive group, not as a ring (unless, as you observe, $e$ happens to be central).

If you want to get an isomorphism of rings, you have to instead put a different multiplication on the decomposition instead of the componentwise multiplication.  The way to do this is to write the components as a $2\times 2$ matrix like $$\begin{pmatrix}eRe & eR(1-e) \\ (1-e)Re & (1-e)R(1-e)\end{pmatrix}$$ and use the usual matrix multiplication formula.  That is, given $(a,b,c,d)\in eRe \oplus (1-e)Re \oplus eR(1-e) \oplus (1-e)R(1-e)$, you think of $(a,b,c,d)$ as the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}.$$  To multiply two elements of $eRe \oplus (1-e)Re \oplus eR(1-e) \oplus (1-e)R(1-e)$, you then just multiply the corresponding matrices according to the usual formula for matrix multiplication.

(To provide some intuition for why this should work, consider the case that $R=M_2(k)$ and $e=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.  Then the four components of the Peirce decomposition just correspond to the four matrix entries of an element of $R$.  For instance, $eRe$ is the set of matrices whose only nonzero entry is the top left entry, $eR(1-e)$ is the set of matrices whose only nonzero entry is the top right entry, and so on.)

The idempotence of $e$ is in fact needed in order to get the additive isomorphism, specifically to get that your map is surjective.  For instance, if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $e=2$, then all the direct summands in the decomposition are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ as groups, so your map is a group-homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}^4$, which cannot be surjective.